# Security of Nativescript ApplicationSettings vs REST API

Tags: nativescript, mobile-development

This is more of a design question, i'm building a NativeScript mobile application where users are restricted by a number of requests per day.  After they login or start the application and I check:

```
public ngOnInit() {
  MAX_TRIES = 1000
  if(ApplicationSettings.getBoolean("authenticated", false){
    if(ApplicationSettings.getNumber("requests", MAX_TRIES) != MAX_TRIES){
      // Then continue, allow user to proceed
    }
  }
```

However coming from using Flask you'd typically want to keep these variables (attempts, wins/losses) in a server side database, however if you're simply storing a key `authenticated` inside ApplicationSettings then i'm guessing it's okay to keep every user variable stored locally?  Or should I avoid ApplicationSettings and just make everything in my application a REST Request?

Comment: As long as it's not a users password or other sensitive info you'd never want to store anyway. I think you'll be fine. I store auth tokens in my NS apps since they're needed to auth against the API with.

Comment: Great thanks for the advice, so there's no significant risk of a user manipulating these and sending malicious requests or adjusting their tries back to 0?

Comment: if someone knew what they were doing, they could end up overwriting the value of the key if they wanted and knew how to use the APIs. Simplest way would be to open the app and find what the `key` is and then run your app. It's a bit of work but possible. Anything on the device can be retrieved is the general rule of thumb I go by. I'm sure some will argue that it's fine and not a concern but given to the person with the will and skills they could get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always good to setup these kind of restrictions on the server side. But if you are left with no choice but doing it in client side,

1. Try encrypting your requests and response so at least any user wouldn't know what is being transmitted / why it fails at first look.
2. Encrypt your production build with JScrambler or AppProtection that makes reverse engineering more difficult
3. Whatever you store locally (in application settings / sqlite / in any file), keep them encrypted rather using plain data.